# Code keeps entering values into array backwards

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this code, where I'm trying to figure out how many forground layers will be in a map :

```
    int layerNum=5 //in the current map it has 5 layers
    int index = 3 //in the current map
    fgLayers = new int[layerNum - (index + 1)];
    for (int x = 0; x < fgLayers.length; x++) {
        fgLayers[x] = layerNum - x - 1;
        Gdx.app.log(ChromeGame.LOG, fgLayers[x] + "");
    }
```

However, it puts the values into the fgLayers array backwards so instead of 3,4 it would 4,3. I need it to be in the right order because each layer has certain images on it, which look improper when placed in a different order.

Unfortunately, I cannot see where I'm going wrond in this piece of code, I tried switching where it starts of at in the for loop (starts at fgLayers.length, ends at 0) but that didnt work either.

Comment: are you getting 3 4?you should get just 4.

Comment: @ihsankocak: I'm getting 4 in fgLayers[0] and 3 in fgLayers[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using JLRishes answer I modified it a bit to work with my code

```
    int topLayerStart = index + 1;
    fgLayers = new int[layerNum - topLayerStart];

    for (int x = 0; x < fgLayers.length; x++) {
        fgLayers[x] = x + topLayerStart;
        Gdx.app.log(ChromeGame.LOG, fgLayers[x] + "");
    }
```

Made the loop at the the index + 1 so the next layer and increase from there.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is increasing, so of course `layerNum - x - 1` will decrease. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could change your for loop to go backwards. Or you could change `layerNum - x - 1` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

```
fgLayers[x] = layerNum - x - 1;
```

When `x` is 0 fgLayers[0] = 5 - 0 - 1 which is 4.

When `x` is 1 fgLayers[1] = 5 - 1 - 1 which is 3.

But the block in the `for` loop is executed only once so you should only get `4` as output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
fgLayers[x] = layerNum - x - 1;
```

use

```
fgLayers[x] = index + x;
```

That will produce the result you described, but it's not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

It also looks like you need to change your array declaration to `new int[layerNum - index];`